Core Data Migration Mapping Model createRelationships crash
I've created a heavyweight migration between two database versions using a mapping model & custom policy. Three types are migrated during this migration map.
However, one (or possibly more) types that do not have a custom policy (i.e. using the default migration mappings for relationships) are crashing during the createRelationships part of the migration.
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException

Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'Y' between objects in different contexts (source = <NSManagedObject: 0x301149ea0> (
entity: X; 
id: 0x9368e08e17960eb2 <x-coredata://B0EDFCC4-3F92-4705-9E8B-92DBF0F8AE1A/Desc/p145>; 
data: { 
  addedDate = "2024-07-11 13:44:52"; 
  capturedBy = nil; 
  capturedDate = nil; 
  Y = nil; flag = 0; 
  negativeImageData = "{length = 50, bytes = 0x89504e47 0d0a1a0a 0000000d 49484452 ... aece1ce9 00000078 }"; 
  objectId = "id123"; 
  parentId = nil; 
  desc = "DESC///s:98,43,5,0,0,0;p:98,43,5,0,0,0;///896///300"; 
  sortDate = "2024-07-11 12:44:52 +0000"; 
  type = a; 
  user = nil; 
}) , destination = <NSManagedObject: 0x3011193b0> (
entity: Y; 
id: 0x9368e08e0ed60d22 <x-coredata://B0EDFCC4-3F92-4705-9E8B-92DBF0F8AE1A/Job/p91>; 
data: <fault>))  


Anyone have any ideas? Since I'm not touching these types in the migration map with a custom policy, I'm not sure how to resolve this one.

"between objects in different contexts" That seems to be the big issue. Are you using two different context?
